# PhoneGap doesn't show iOS build

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, phonegap, devextreme

I'm developing a hybrid mobile app using PhoneGap as a build tool.

**Enviroment:**
Visual Studio 2015
DevExteme library

PhoneGap cli version 8.0.0
Cordova iOS version 5.0.0
Plugin added: `Cordova Support Google Services` and `Cordova Plugin Firebase Analytics`
Development certificate for iOS unlocked on my PhoneGap account


**Steps:**

- Build a PhoneGap Zip.
- Upload the code on PhoneGap account.
- Build the app.

**The problem:** PhoneGap doesn't show iOS build, but only Android (which works perfectly on device)
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,
Sara

**Edit: 2019-03-07**
As requested, I add `config.xml`.

```
<widget id="com.devexpress.apptemplate" version="1.0" versionCode="1">
  <name>ApplicationTemplate</name>
  <description>Template</description>
  <author email="email@sample.com" href="http://sample.com">Author</author>
  <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="60000" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
  <preference name="cordova-ios" version="5.0.0" />
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.0.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" onload="true" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" onload="true" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm"></plugin>

  <platform name="ios">
     <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
  </platform>

  <plugin name ="cordova-support-google-services" />
  <plugin name ="cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Can you give us you'r config.xml please ?

Comment: yeah, sure. I added it at the end of the original post.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the build phonegap site? if yes, post it